# What do you need to do to earn crate keys?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have a Chroma 2 Case, but I need a key. How do I get one?

Answer (score 2):

You can't earn a key. The only (somewhat legal) way to obtain a key is trough the steam market, buying one yourself (when you click the "Open" button, you'll be prompted to buy one). Another way is to receive it trough trade, many players trade skins for keys (basically turning skins into rl money)

TBH Another way to obtain a key is to sell your own skins (which is not advisable as cases never have anything good in them ...) What is my recommendation is to save the cases. Save every case you have and sell it in some time. I once started destroying cases as I tough they'd sell for 0.03$ which isn't that much and towards the last of my cases i noticed that they actually sell for like .50$ ...

Comment: *"which is not advisable as cases never have anything good in them ..."* not necessarily true, though the chance of getting a decent skin (profit wise), is low.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Well of course, cases have anything from light-blue 0.03$ skins, to $10 000+ knifes. But as you mentioned the odds are not in our favor, quite far from it actually.  The chance is someting close to 0.01 or 0.05% to get a knife. I'll try to find a youtube video about this later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a key. Its fairly straight forward to buy one(just try to open a case). Now if you want to get keys without spending money you will need to go to other external websites and start betting or doing other stuff. I would not recommend doing this as many sites are shady. So if you really want to open the case just buy the case from inside the game.

Comment: Why can you earn cases without being ble to earn keys?

Comment: @13cutlerd So people would _buy_ the keys. This has been Valve's business model for a while. Give them boxes for free. But _sell_ the keys.

Comment: Because this is how the micro-transaction system in CS:GO works. You earn "free" cases that need a paid key to be opened. There is no other way around this, if you want to complain write a email to valve and tell them to start giving away keys